# How to prevent emacs from popping up with new frames in response to dedicated windows? I would much rather it split the existing window

Tags: frames, window-splitting, dedicated-windows

I've recently started using dedicated windows because I have certain windows (a python interpreter, sometimes a PDF of a LaTeX document), that I do not want obstructed under any circumstances. This mostly works great, except sometimes, I run a command that wants to open a new window and instead of splitting the window, it opens a whole new frame!

For an MWE of this issue, if you have AucTeX, try creating a buffer with the .tex extension and paste in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
(progn 
  (defun toggle-window-dedicated ()
    "Control whether or not Emacs is allowed to display another
buffer in current window."
    (interactive)
    (message
     (if (let (window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
         (set-window-dedicated-p window (not (window-dedicated-p window))))
         "%s: Can't touch this!"
         "%s is up for grabs.")
     (current-buffer))
   (force-mode-line-update)
  )
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'toggle-window-dedicated)
(turn-on-reftex))
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{fish}
\end{equation}
\eqref{fish}
\end{document}
```

First, evaluate the great big Elisp expression that I randomly put in the middle of my TeX file. Next, split your frame into two windows using `C-x 2` or `C-x 3`. Type `C-c d` to make your current window dedicated, then `C-x o` to switch to the other, non-dedicated window. Now move the cursor the the word `fish` in `\eqref{fish}` and type `C-c &` to find the label its referring to.

Emacs opens a new frame! I have confirmed that Emacs25 has this behavior with a blank `.emacs`.

If you tried the same behavior with a frame containing only one window, Emacs sensibly splits the window. I would like Emacs to always split windows in situations like this, and never open new frames unless I explicitly request it.

First, Is there a way to do that? Second, should I file a bug report?

Comment: (elisp)[Dedicated Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html).

Comment: @Drew While I've looked at that page before, I hadn't noticed the section on frame behavior, so thanks for pointing that out. It doesn't actually appear to directly address this precise situation. In particular, I don't think any of them discuss the possibility of a new frame opening, unless I'm missing something?